# Running java with JAVA_OPTS env variable has no effect

Tags: java, shell, remote-debugging, jvm-arguments

In a shell script, I have set the JAVA_OPTS environment variable (to enable remote debugging and increase memory), and then I execute the jar file as follows:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=n -Xms512m -Xmx512m"
java -jar analyse.jar $*
```

But it seems there is no effect of the JAVA_OPTS env variable as I cannot connect to remote-debugging and I see no change in memory for the JVM.

What could be the problem?

PS: I cannot use those settings in the `java -jar analyse.jar $*` command because I process command line arguments in the application.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I don't know of any JVM that actually checks the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable.  Usually this is used in scripts which launch the JVM and they usually just add it to the `java` command-line.

The key thing to understand here is that arguments to `java` that come *before* the `-jar analyse.jar` bit will only affect the JVM and *won't* be passed along to your program.  So, modifying the `java` line in your script to:

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -jar analyse.jar $*
```

Should "just work".

Comment: See HEX's answer.  That is how you set the options using an environment variable on OS X.

Answer (score 104):

You can setup `_JAVA_OPTIONS` instead of `JAVA_OPTS`. This should work without `$_JAVA_OPTIONS`.

Comment: _This_ this the real answer.  I went looking around for hours to find this.

Comment: @Nerrve Special for you installed Windows XP. Works fine. Are you sure you did everything correctly?

Comment: @Nerrve You must create environment variable called `_JAVA_OPTIONS`. Example: http://cs417020.userapi.com/v417020976/3764/hwBZ419TXcQ.jpg

Comment: oops! you're right. its works! i had made a spelling mistake earlier :P thanks a bunch!

Comment: You may also would use JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327620/difference-between-java-options-java-tool-options-and-java-opts)

Comment: @Hubbitus your suggestion appears to be the correct answer. you should add it

Comment: I can't. I got "Trivial answer converted to comment"

Comment: Holy moly this worked. Why is this so badly documented?

Comment: Beware: this prints a line to stderr

Comment: Thanks, I was able to set `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable using Java 8u282 running in a Docker container and it was picked up!

Answer (score 6):

In the past 12 years some changes were made:

- **Environment variable `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS`**: this is the recommended way to do what you wanted starting with Java 9, see [Using the JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS Launcher Environment Variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE__USINGTHEJDK_JAVA_OPTIONSLAUNCHERENV-F3C0E3BA) in the Oracle Java 9 documentation, and this comprehensive answer [What is the difference between JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS and JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS when using Java 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52986487/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-java-options-and-java-tool-options-when-using).
- Environment variable `JAVA_OPTS`: it was NOT and is NOT a standardized option. Some shell script wrappers for Java based tools do evaluate it, an example of how this works is in the answer from ZoogieZork.
- Environment variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS` (mentioned by HEX): it is nowadays deprecated/undocumented, see [Oracle announcement](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/9-enhancements.html) (section "`Add a new launcher environment variable JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS`").