# Unable to set JVM parameters/arguments (Xmx and Xms) through .bat file

Tags: java, batch-file, jvm

I am able to run a Java program through Eclipse by setting the VM arguments as -Xmx1024m
-Xms256M. Now I want to run the same Java program (jar) through a .bat file in Windows. I am setting the JVM values in the file as follows

```
@echo off
set JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -Xms256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
java -cp TA.jar com.myClass
```

But when I run the same program through batch (.bat in Windows XP) it throws Out of Memory error and I suspect that the JVM setting through the .bat file is not working.

Comment: Have you tried simply passing the options instead of setting the environment variable?

Comment: @Michael Myers I didnt quite understand what you meant.. sorry..

Comment: I mean `java -Xmx1024m -Xms256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -cp TA.jar com.myClass` instead of messing with JAVA_OPTS

Comment: possible dupe?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011311/running-java-with-java-opts-env-variable

Comment: @MichaelMyers: When I tried that it is showing the error - Could not find or load main class Xmx1024m

Comment: @Bohemian - you shouldn't have deleted your answer. JAVA_OPTS is by no means used automatically by the JVM.

Comment: @paulb: `java -cp TA.jar com.myClass -Xmx1024m -Xms256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the arguments directly

```
java -Xmx1024m -Xms256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -cp TA.jar com.myClass
```

You don't need to set them at `JAVA_OPTIONS`. To be sure that your application is using the parameters that you want:

- open `jvisualvm` that comes with java. Just type "jvisualvm" at command line if you have set java correctly at your path.
- open the vm started to your application.
- check under "JVM Arguments" in the "[Overview](http://visualvm.java.net/overview_tab.html)" tab.

There should be set your jvm options.

Comment: I have to pass some input paramentes as arguments from the command prompt. so in reality my bat file is java -cp TA.jar com.myClass %1 %2 . In this case where should I place the JVM paramters as per your approach.

Comment: you could set it before the -cp. Editing the answer.

Answer (score 11):

It should be _JAVA_OPTIONS instead of JAVA_OPTS.

Comment: Thanks Danyel.. It worked.. I used : set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx1024m -Xms256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

Comment: this should be the real answer