# Linux - Java - Error occurred during initialization of VM

Tags: java, linux, jvm

I have gone through SO for similar questions but none of them gave a correct working answer w.r.t my setup (the answers on the other questions were applicable for Windows machine, 64-bit).

I have the following setup:

```
$ 
$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.8.4-102.fc17.i686 #1 SMP Sun Mar 24 13:20:55 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
$ 
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
$ 
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_17
$ 
$ 
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3520       3435         85          0        472       1531
-/+ buffers/cache:       1431       2089
Swap:         5567          0       5567
$ 
$ 
$ echo $JAVA_HOME 
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17
$ 
$ echo $PATH 
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17/bin
$
```

I am getting the following error when attempting to run java programs!

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Do I need to upgrade to `64-bit OS` and install `64-bit JVM`? or should I upgrade my hardware with more `RAM`?

Comment: What is the command line that you use to launch the program. Do you specify any Xmx/Xms values? Please provide the complete command line.

Comment: It's quite obvious that it wasn't able to allocate memory for the JVM (heap). What is the command line or script that you used to launch the  program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please visit [Running java with JAVA_OPTS env variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011311/running-java-with-java-opts-env-variable), HEX provides that you should set up _JAVA_OPTIONS variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if you have any JAVA_OPTS defined: `echo $JAVA_OPTS`. Do you specify any heap size?

First you can try to allocate more RAM for your machine.

Second, you can try and run your java command with specified MaxHeapSize and maybe Xmx/Xms.
Check out [Tuning the JVM heap sizes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm#i1110833) in the Oracle's docs.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the memory, you just have 85mb available. You might want to free some memory before launching your program. Also, try running it with the following command line options: 
`-Xmx512m`, `-XX:MaxHeapSize=256m`