# How to set permanent memory settings for java?

Tags: java, memory, jvm-arguments

I use jre-7u40-linux-x64 on SL6.4.
Server with more than 30Gb of RAM. User's memory limits sets to several gigabytes, but 
command java returns error.
"Not enough memory heap..."

Under root it's ok and -XshowSettings:vm shows that memory size is automaticaly estimated.

Under user with options -Xmx256m it's ok also.

So is it possible to set the property(-Xmx256m) permanently?

I tried environtment variables (JAVA_OPTS,JAVA_OPTIONS) and jvm.cfg. With no results.

Any advices and keywords?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

JAVA_OPTS / JAVA_OPTIONS do not help: [Running java with JAVA_OPTS env variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011311/running-java-with-java-opts-env-variable)

However, if you want such feature, you can create a simple shell script.

A script called java in a location that is in user's PATH environment variable before the actual java binary should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/java/oracle/bin/java "$JAVA_OPTS" "$@"
```