# What is the difference between JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS and JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS when using Java 11?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments, java-11

What is the exact difference between [JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE__USINGTHEJDK_JAVA_OPTIONSLAUNCHERENV-F3C0E3BA) and [JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/troubleshoot/environment-variables-and-system-properties.html#GUID-BE6E7B7F-A4BE-45C0-9078-AA8A66754B97) when using Java 11?

I'm using a tiny test program:

```
public class Foo {
  public static final void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("arg: " + System.getProperty("arg"));
  }
}
```

The two environment variables seem to do the same, but the output is slightly different.  That makes me believe they might have different use cases:

```
$ JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Darg=jdk" java Foo
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: -Darg
arg: jdk

$ JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Darg=tool" java Foo
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Darg
arg: tool

$ JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS="illegalArg" java Foo
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: illegalArg
Error: Cannot specify main class in environment variable JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS

$ JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="illegalArg" java Foo
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: illegalArg
Unrecognized option: illegalArg
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

It seems like `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` have precedence over `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`:

```
$ JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Darg=jdk" JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Darg=tool" java Foo
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: -Darg=jdk
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Darg=tool
arg: jdk
```

But ultimately the command line wins:

```
$ JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Darg=jdk" JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Darg=tool" java -Darg=cmd Foo
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: -Darg=jdk
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Darg=tool
arg: cmd
```

When building, though, only `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` is read:

```
$ JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Darg=jdk" JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Darg=tool" javac Foo.java
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Darg=tool
```

I'm currently using AdoptOpenJDK 11 build 28.

Comment: aren't they supposedly the environment variable which you can define as you want?

Comment: @nullpointer I'm not sure what you mean?  Both can successfully be used to set options for `java`, but they seem to be implemented slightly different (based on the output from the `java` command).

Comment: Some related stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327620/difference-between-java-options-java-tool-options-and-java-opts , https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8185446

Comment: @Henry Thanks, I've seen those.  They don't address my question, though...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The functional difference between the two variables is explained by @gjoranv's answer.

The differences in the output I think stem from the following:

1. The two variables seem to be implemented in different points in the launching process.
2. The `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` documentation says:

   > In order to mitigate potential misuse of JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS behavior, options that specify the main class (such as -jar) or cause the java launcher to exit without executing the main class (such as -h) are disallowed in the environment variable. If any of these options appear in the environment variable, the launcher will abort with an error message.

   This line:

   ```
    Error: Cannot specify main class in environment variable JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS
   ```

   is the error message that warns the user of a potential attempt to do mayhem via that variable.

   I think that `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` takes precedence, in part for the same reason.

Answer (score 43):

- `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` is only picked up by the `java` launcher, so use it for options that you only want to apply (or only make sense for) the java startup command. This variable is also new on JDK 9+, and will be ignored by earlier JDK versions. Hence, it's useful when migrating from older versions to 9+.
- `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` is picked up also by other java tools like `jar` and `javac` so it should be used for flags that you want to apply (and are valid) to all those java tools.