# Passing java_opts to spring boot applications in kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment

Currently, we are building Docker images with an entrypoint and passing this image to a Kubernetes deployment.

Is there any way to pass the entrypoint directly to Kubernetes dynamically so that it starts spring boot applications?

What are the different ways of passing this entrypoint directly in Kubernetes?

```
### Runtime image ###
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

#Set working dir
WORKDIR /test

# Copy the executable JAR
COPY /*.jar /test/

# Run the app
ENTRYPOINT java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djsversion=1.0 -D<variable>=<service-1> -D<variable>=<service-2>   -jar  *.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `command` in k8s deployment manifest:

```
containers:
- name: mycontainer
  env:
  - name: NAME
    value: VALUE
  command: [ "java"]
  args: ["-jar", "-D..."]
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.. I have 100's of microservices with same arguments,... Is it possible to do using configmaps... as it is easy for me to change in one place,... otherwise I need to change the argument values in each and every deployment yaml file

Comment: You can't put the command into a config map, but you can put the environment variable values into a config map.

Comment: Yes, I got it... but how do I pass the config-maps along with command... so that it will start the java process along with container.  Could you please provide me with an sample yaml file... I am a new-bie, kindly please help

Comment: Take a look at this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data You can use configmaps to set your environment variables for pods, and build your images to use those environment variables,

Comment: Thanks @Burak for the help much appreciated!!!    created the configmap and passed the env variables as below                                                                                           
         command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "$(SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY)" ]
          env:
            - name: SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: javaconfig
                  key: JAVA_OPTS                                                                                             Now I am able to call and start the java services. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could also include it in your kubernetes deployment yaml file alongside the rest of your environment variables that you wish to pass into your docker container:

```
- name: JAVA_OPTS
  value: >-
        -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom 
        -Djsversion=1.0 -D<variable>=<service-1> -D<variable>=<service-2>
- name: SERVER_PORT
  value: 8080
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JAVA version 9+ be aware that name of env variable `JAVA_OPTS` changed.

More in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/52989562/8918153

Answer (score 0):

You can set them as env variables in your pod's config

```
env:
      - name: MY_POD_IP
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: status.podIP
      - name: profile
        value: "dev"
```

then use them in Dockerfile's like so

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=$profile rest.war"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments... I don't want to place CMD/Entrypoint in Dockerfile... and I am looking to pass with kubernetes deployment dynamically so that I no need to build the docker images for any changes in JAVA_OPTS parameters