# Jacoco agent (output=file) not (creating /writing to) file .exec(not using any maven plugins)

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco

I have a spring boot rest service(`Spring-Boot-Jacoco-Example`) and I followed https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html and  downloaded `org.jacoco.agent-0.8.4-.jar` and set the following JAVA_OPTS in a windows machine

`set JAVA_OPTS=-javaagent:C:\Workspace\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.4-.jar,append=true,includes=*,output=file,destfile=C:\Workspace\Github\Spring-Boot-Jacoco-Example\target\jacoco.exec`

and I did echoed it and JAVA_OPTS are set [image]

I started the app from the cmd `java -jar Spring-Boot-Jacoco-Example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and it hit the rest end point and shut down the app `ctrl+c` and looked at the target folder and I don't see any .exec file in the target folder.

I need suggestions or possible solutions inorder to generate .exec file with this method(*I don't want to use maven plugin*)

Github repo:https://github.com/BhargavModepalli/Spring-Boot-jacoco-Example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011311/running-java-with-java-opts-env-variable-has-no-effect solved the issue