# Kubernetes - how to pass truststore path and password to JVM arguments

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, dockerfile, ssl-certificate, configmap

I need to add jks file to my JVM for SSL Handshake with the server. The JKS is mounted in volume and available to the docker container. How do I pass the JKS truststore path and password to the Springboot(JVM) during start up.
One option I think is as an environment variables (-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore, -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword) . For Openshift, following works as described in the url below.

Option 1:

```
      env:
          - name: JAVA_OPTIONS
            value: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/run/secrets/java.io/keystores/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/11/22/dynamically-creating-java-keystores-openshift/

But, I don't seem to find similar JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable for Kubernetes.

Option2 :

My Docker file is:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-apline
..........
........
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "xxx.jar"]
```

Can this be changed as below and the $JAVA_OPTS can be set as env variable to JVM via configmap?

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-apline
..........
........
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -jar xxx.jar" ]
```

Configmap:

```
JAVA_OPTS: "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/run/secrets/java.io/keystores/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"
```

Please suggest if this would work or anyother better solutions. More preferred if we can get store the password in secret.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options:

**1:** You can break it all up and use [secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#:%7E:text=Using%20Secrets%20as%20environment%20variables&text=Create%20a%20secret%20or%20use,key%20you%20wish%20to%20consume.) to store your credentials only as env vars, secret to store the keystore which can be mounted as a file on disk in the container, and a ConfigMap to hold other java options as env variables then use an entrypoint script in your container to validate and mash it all together to form the JAVA_OPTS string.

**2:** You can put the whole string in a JAVA_OPTS secret that you consume at run-time.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-env-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    image: myimage
    env:
      - name: JAVA_OPTS
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: JAVA_OPTS
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do this in a K8s deployment using `_JAVA_OPTION` environment variable for a Spring Boot 2.3.x application in Docker container running Java 8 (Got tip for this envvar from this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11615960/309261).

```yaml
      env:
        - name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
          value: >
            -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/truststore.jks
            -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```